# How to correctly set a key of a Generic Interface as key of the interface

Tags: typescript

I need help with TypeScript generics; how can I access the T["value"] field within the `ActionAdd` interface?

```
type UserValue = { username: string; };

interface User {
  id: number;
  value: UserValue;
}

interface ActionAdd<T = unknown> {
  type: "ADD";
  value: T["value"]; // Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
}

type UserAction = ActionAdd<User>;
```

`T` object will always have `{ value }` key, doesn't have to be `unknown` type - but the object will have other keys as well.

I have tried:

```
interface ActionAdd<T, K extends keyof T> {
  type: "ADD";
  value: T[K];
}

type UserAction = ActionAdd<User, "value">;
```

OR:

```
interface ActionAdd<T = unknown> {
  type: "ADD";
  value: T extends { value: infer V } ? V : never;
}

type UserAction = ActionAdd<User>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` will always have a `value` key then you need to tell the compiler that by [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to `{value: unknown}`:

```
interface ActionAdd<T extends { value: unknown }> {
  type: "ADD";
  value: T["value"]; // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgNQIYBsCu0C8UDeUmCiAdqgLYQBcUcwiAlqQOYDcUAvmwLABQ-ZsCQAzVAGNo8JAX5QojACa1SmCgCMkvPvIBuGbLWkoDEbZ36DSwxGMlQAguOCMA9qQeLFAHgAqUCAAPYVJFOAIofSwaIlIAa1JXAHdSLgA+WR0oUEhaACIHABFCvO09U1pfAG08qOw8gF1zSz4cqRInF3coPE63Dy9vYzTtIA)

Comment: Thank you, I'm nearly there. I have edited my question with a playground link, do you know if I can fix this issue without casting `as unknown as T`?

Comment: You've changed the scope of the question in response to my answer in order to deal with the next problem you ran into.  That's not how things are really supposed to work; if you have a followup question, please make a followup post.